# How to add objects to an array during creation using a loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write some meta information for a website (using `vue-meta`) and I need to add some `tags` as objects within an array named `meta`.

The code is like this:

```
metaInfo() {
            return {
                htmlAttrs: { lang: "en"
                },
                title: this.Post.Title,
                meta: [
                    {
                        name: "description", content: this.Post.Title
                    },
                    {
                        name: "date", content: this.Post.DateCreated
                    },
                    {
                        name: "author", content: this.Post.Author
                    },

               // Now I need multiple objects of: {name: "tag", content: "Tags.TagName"} like this but doesn't work:
               function() {
                    this.Tags.forEach(function (TagName, index) {

                    { property: "tag", content: "TagName" }

                    })
                    }
                ],
        }
        }
```

How can I create my array so that I end up with this for example:

```
 meta: [
                    {
                        name: "description", content: "Javascript question"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "date", content: "20200421"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "author", content: "volumeone"
                    },
                    {   property: "tag", content: "Javascript" }
                    ,
                    {   property: "tag", content: "Programming" }
                    ,
                    {   property: "tag", content: "Newbie" }

                ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can do such sort of thing.

```
              var meta = [{
name: "description", content: this.Post.Title
},
{
name: "date", content: this.Post.DateCreated
},
{
name: "author", content: this.Post.Author
}]

this.Tags.forEach(function (TagName, index) {
  meta.push({ property: "tag", content: "TagName" })
})
metaInfo() {
            return {
                htmlAttrs: { lang: "en"
                },
                title: this.Post.Title,
// or you can just write "meta" instead of "meta: meta" its an shorthand // code 
                    meta: meta
        }

    }
```

Comment: So my whole `meta` array has to be created first and then returned as part of the `metaInfo()` method in my code?

Comment: let me send complete example to you, then you will clearly understant it

Comment: check the updated answer and let me know if you understand it

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you can just use push and pass the object.

```js
var meta = [];
meta.push({"property" : "tag","content" : "test"});
console.log(meta);
```

Comment: So I can only add to an array using a loop after the `meta` array is created but not during?

Comment: a variable should be outside the loop whereas `meta.push()` should be  inside the loop

Comment: @volumeone, you can't add to an array the way you are doing it. You either have to initialize or use push inside of your loop but not as a return like you are doing it.

Comment: @imvain2 thank you, finally understood it :) JS is quite different to what I'm used to